copy html table with dropdown menu into excel vba
Good morning to all. Let's see if someone can help me out with this, cause it is making me crazy. I´ve been looking all over to try to make this work on Excel and still can´t make it happen.
I have a webpage, with a dropdown menu for selection, and then it presents a table that i want to copy to excel using VBA.
Webpage: https://www.bancobpi.pt/cotacoes
In here, i find 4 options:

Câmbios
Fundos de Investimento
PPR
Seguros de Capitalização

I Want to select the second one "Fundos de Investimento", wait for IE to load the page and then fill the cells on an excel page.
What i have so far is making IE open and waiting for it to load completely, but i can't get pass that :(.
Sub demo()
 Dim IE
 Dim ro As Integer
 Dim Table As Object
 Dim trows As Object
 Dim r As Object
 Dim tcells As Object
 Dim c As Object
 Dim objIE As Object
 Dim Title As Object
 

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://www.bancobpi.pt/cotacoes"

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set Title = IE.Document.getElementById("wt2_LT_SitePublico_wt151_block_wtContent_wtContent_CW_SP_Fragments_wt3_block_LT_SitePublico_wt10_block_wtLeftContent_LT_SitePublico_Patterns_wt165_block_wtForm_LT_SitePublico_Patterns_wt51_block_wtRow_LT_SitePublico_Patterns_wt228_block_wtInput_wtSelAcoes")
    Title.selectedIndex = 1
    
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

    Set Table = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")
    Set trows = Table(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")

     ro = 1
     For Each r In trows
          Set tcells = r.getElementsByTagName("td")
            For Each c In tcells
                
                Debug.Print (c.innerText)
                
                ro = ro + 1
            Next
     Next

End Sub


You could try putting DoEvents within your Do While... loop to give Excel a chance to update.

... But it looks to me like you will have a lot of work to navigate to the table you want inside that IE instance and get hold of the table. You could look at using the Data menu in Excel, which allows extracting data from an HTML page, but I suspect manipulating the drop-down list to get the right table may be problematic. Have you asked the bank if there is a URL you can use to get direct to the table you need?

I did, no answer from there :(

Well, managed to get something, nut now the problem is that the page doesn't update with selection on drop-down menu.

Seems no luck anywhere :(. I´ve tried alot of things, and still nothing. Only getting values from first table.

Well seems no one can help me out with this. Going to keep trying to fix this :(
